# SSRS: SUM values if contending with NULLS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In SSMS, this is easy with an `ISNULL` function. So in SSRS, how would I go about getting a `SUM` value from two columns where one of them has `NULLS`?

Here's an example of the data:

[image]

So if a `pro_rate` value exists, I want to use it in the aggregation, but if it is NULL, then I need to pull from the `cost` column. Here's my most recent attempt at the expression:

```
=iif(isnothing(sum(Fields!pro_rate.Value), sum(Fields!cost.Value), sum(Fields!pro_rate.Value)))
```

In SQL, I would simply write `sum(isnull(pro_rate, cost))`(to also ensure it's clear what my result should be) but I keep getting the dreaded `#Error` in my report.

---

**UPDATE 1:** I altered my query a bit to the following and got the #Error.

```
=sum(iif(isnothing(Fields!pro_rate.Value), Fields!cost.Value, Fields!pro_rate.Value))
```

[image]

Comment: The actual "dreaded #error" normally shows in the output pane in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm actually using SQL Report Builder, but if I'm understanding your question, yes I get that error when trying my query. I'll add screenshot to question.

Comment: My point is that somewhere in your report designer (or report log) there will be further information about what is actually causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at your data and the expressions being used, I came to the conclusion that you are seeing that error message due to a conversion error.  It looks like your `cost` field is an `INT` datatype as the values all seem to be rounded off to the nearest integer and the `pro_rate` field appears to be a `DECIMAL` datatype.  This appears to cause a problem when you are attempting to `SUM` an integer into a decimal without the proper level of precision.

To test this, I created the following simple dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (A VARCHAR(2), B INT, C DECIMAL(4,2))

INSERT INTO #temp (A,B,C)
VALUES ('A', '5', '1.7'), ('B', '10', '2.6'), ('C', '9', NULL)

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

With this data, I was able to test and confirm that my theory was correct and you should be able to fix your `#Error` by putting a `CDEC` function around the `cost` field in the expression provided by [Derrick Moeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204764/10755978).

[image]

Comment: Never even heard of CDEC. Brilliant answer, thank you so much! This is such good information to have, as it worked beautifully.

Comment: Happy to help -- there's a whole set of conversion functions like `CStr`, `CInt`, `CDec`, and it's surprising how often mismatched datatypes can cause issues.

Comment: So I'm going to go out on a limb and presume these are shorthand for convert decimal, convert string, convert integer, etc.? Awesome info my friend.

Comment: Correct, [here's a complete list of available conversion functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions).

Comment: Oh I see, so conversely I could've used a CINT on both C.Value's (to reference your example)?

Comment: That would technically work, but I think in this case, you'd want to use `CDEC` because a `CINT` will round the decimal values of `pro_rate` to the nearest full integer so the sum wouldn't be accurate.  However, you'd only need the `CINT` in the second instance of `C` as the `IsNothing` function doesn't care about datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to evaluate each row individually and you have your order of operations incorrect.

```
=sum(iif(isnothing(Fields!pro_rate.Value), Fields!cost.Value, Fields!pro_rate.Value))
```